# Is it safe to use sizeof operator on non-POD types in C++

Tags: c++

Is it safe to use `sizeof` operator on non-POD types in C++? Will this value greater or equal the size of all of its members?

Comment: For sure it is not safe without the knowledge about the data type.

Comment: You could always check out the [reference material](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course it's safe. And note also that `sizeof` is evaluated at *compile-time*.

The `sizeof` a non-POD type will never be *less* than the total of the size of all its members, excepting any empty base class optimisations.

It could well be *greater* than the total of the size of all its members, due to packing arrangements and the fact that a class with no members will have a non-zero `sizeof`.

Comment: What about empty base class optimization?

Comment: @NathanOliver: Yes that's interesting but can you conjure up an example where you actually *get* a zero `sizeof`? In any such instance, I think that the empty base class optimisation is not permitted. But would love to be proven wrong on this: something to mull over during the weekend.

Comment: Not really for `sizeof(X) == 0` but [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6955090c4ba3273e).  The whole is less then the parts.

Comment: Yes that's a good point. Drink on me. I've nicked your comment.

Comment: No problem.  I was curious so I had to test it.  Thanks for adding it.  I'll take a scotch ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Sizeof is guaranteed to return enough bytes to hold the object, including any padding and other types of "hidden" fields, such as the padding to serialize it.

The perhaps only caveat is that being evaluated at compile time, it is not polimorphic. 
That is,

```
class Base
{
    int x;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    int y;
};

int main()
{
    Base* k = new Derived;

    return sizeof(*k)/sizeof(int);
}
```

returns `1` rather than `2`, that is it evaluates to its formal type `Base` even though the object is in fact a `Derived` at run time.

Answer (score 2):

According to the working draft, [[5.3.3/2]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.sizeof#2):

> When applied to a class, the result is the number of bytes in an object of that class including any padding required for placing objects of that type in an array. The size of a most derived class shall be greater than zero. The result of applying sizeof to a base class subobject is the size of the base class type.

[Here](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.sizeof#footnote-77) the footnote related to the last sentence:

> The actual size of a base class subobject may be less than the result of applying sizeof to the subobject, due to virtual base classes and less strict padding requirements on base class subobjects.

So: yes, it is safe and the results is more or less *greater or equal the size of all of its members*.